# pycharm console unicode to readable string

Tags: python, pycharm

studying python with [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZxiJ92-4Qys&index=5&list=WL)

The problem is when i trying to get cyrillic characters i get unicode in pycharm console.

[image]

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import operator
import codecs

def start(url):
    word_list = []
    source_code = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code)

    for post_text in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'b-tasks__item__title js-set-visited'}):
        content = post_text.string

        words = content.lower().split()
        for each_word in words:
            word_list.append(each_word)
    clean_up_list(word_list)



def clean_up_list(word_list):
    clean_word_list = []
    for word in word_list:
        symbols = "!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:<>?,./;'[]\=-\""
        for i in range(0, len(symbols)):
            word = word.replace(symbols[i], "")
        if len(word) > 0:
            clean_word_list.append(word)
    create_dictionary(clean_word_list)



def create_dictionary(clean_word_list):
    word_count = {}
for word in clean_word_list:
    if word in word_count:
        word_count[word] += 1
    else:
        word_count[word] = 1

for key, value in sorted(word_count.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)):
    print(key, value)
```

When i am changing **print(key, value)** to **print(key.decode('utf8'), value)** i am getting "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-7: ordinal not in range(128)"

[image]

start('https://youdo.com/tasks-all-opened-all-moscow-1')
There is some suggestion on the internet about changing encoding in some files - don't really get it. Can't i read it in console? 
OSX

**UPD** 
key.encode("utf-8") [image]

Comment: *encode*, not decode.

Comment: endcode doesn't help either, i forgot to tell https://leto12h.storage.yandex.net/rdisk/7542b806b8131d628b2d2c130db803ca7d95f555b0fd6e0ea9c2bcacc898b38d/inf/FbgCBUYw8cjaFgtIj_Ts4tmTlk4y02jJxQHa2XBfel9TkrFy7Db3bI6xxGIrZg6jBbEUGeCswV_4vfTEJl5bLQ==?uid=0&filename=2015-05-15%2014-00-47%201.py%20-%20untitled%20-%20%5B%7E%20PycharmProjects%20untitled%5D.png&disposition=inline&hash=&limit=0&content_type=image%2Fpng&tknv=v2&rtoken=b1577401cae5f5d42e2af1c8929d3b7d&force_default=no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UTF-8 is sometimes painful. I created a file with a line in Latin caracters and another one with Russian ones. The following code:

```
# encoding: utf-8

with open("testing.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    line = f.read()
    print(line)
```

outputs in PyCharm

[image]

Note the two `encoding` entries

Since you are getting data from a web page, you must make sure that you use the right encoding as well. The following code

```
# encoding: utf-8
r = requests.get('http://www.pravda.ru/')
r.encoding = 'utf-8'
print(r.text)
```

outputs in PyCharm as

[image]

Please note that you must specifically set the encoding to match the one of the page.